# Evitar un registro duplicado en C# SIN SQL

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy haciendo un programa de registro de información pero me hace falta agregar algo que evite que si se añade una misma información de un mensaje que ese dato esta duplicado, estoy usando listas pero es lo único que me falta y ya intente de todo.
Les dejo el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        readonly List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        int num = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.PrintMenu();
        }
        public void PrintMenu()
        {
            bool valid = false;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Capturador de Email");
                Console.WriteLine("\nFavor de escoger la opcion que necesites");
                Console.WriteLine("1.- Registrar Email");
                Console.WriteLine("2.- Ver Email Registrados");
                Console.WriteLine("3.- Salir");

                int opc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (opc)
                {
                    case 1:
                        SaveEmails();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ReadEmails();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        valid = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Opcion no valida");
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                }
            } while (valid == false);
        }
        public void SaveEmails()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("¿Cuantos Email quieres registrar?");
            num = UInt16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (num > 0 && num <= 30)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    bool validMail;
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Escribe el email #" + (i + 1));
                        string correo = Console.ReadLine();
                        if ((correo.Contains(".com") || correo.Contains(".es") || correo.Contains(".gob")) && correo.Contains("@")) //Aqui se buscara que los email no se repitan y que tengan @ y que terminen en .com .es o .gob                                                                                                                             
                        {

                            emails.Add(correo);
                            validMail = true;

                        }
                        
                        else 
                        {
                            
                                Console.WriteLine("Formato no valido o repetido \nPresione cualquier tecla para reintentar");
                                Console.ReadLine();
                                validMail = false;
                            
                        }
                    } while (validMail == false);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El maximo de almacenado es 30 correos \nPresione ENTER para continuar");
                Console.ReadLine();
                SaveEmails();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nCorreos almacenados correctamente.  \nPresione ENTER para regresar al menu");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void ReadEmails()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Lista de correos almacenados:\n");

            foreach (string email in emails)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(email);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nLectura completa \nPresione ENTER para regresar al menu");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Como puedo evitar que si se ingrese un dato similar al anterior el programa lo detecte y te diga que ese ya esta en la lista?
Usando arrays no me funciono y con los contain al fin se puede cumplir ciertas expectativas, solo me falta evitar que si se ingresa un email similar a uno el programa te diga que ya esta enlistado y que ingreses otro

Comment: similar no es lo mismo que igual, necesitas que sea similar o igual?

Comment: "Usando arrays no me funcionó". No veo ese código en el programa. ¿Puedes ponernos en la pregunta el código que has probado y explicarnos qué ha pasado?

Comment: Quite los arrays y lo hice en listas, necesito que si el dato es igual el programa de el aviso que ya estaba registrado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando lista esto es muy sencillo, usando linq puedes hacer lo siguiente, antes de ingresar el correo, después de la validación de las extensiones de dominio.

```
if (!emails.Any(c => c == correo))
{
    emails.Add(correo);
    validMail = true;
}
```

Comment: Si es asi... entonces si un correo existe, entonces agrego el nuevo? seria !emails.Any? asi si da falso, entonces agrego el nuevo... si se repitio, no lo agrego.. Igual usualmente estas preguntas que parecen ejercicios se tienen que resolver escribiendo la funcion de validacion...

Comment: Si tienes razón.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (emails.Where(e => e == correo).Count() == 0)
{
    emails.Add(correo);
    validMail = true;
}
```

Se usa el **método Count** de **Linq**, el cual retorna un número que representa el total de correos que hay en la lista que son iguales al que se está insertando, de ser **0** quiere decir que no hay ningún elemento en la lista que coincida con el valor que se está tratando de insertar, de ser mayor que **0** entonces quiere decir que ya existen elementos en la lista iguales al elemento que se está insertando.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

La clase `List<>` tiene un método llamado `Contains(...)` que puedes utilizar de la siguiente manera:

```
if (!emails.Contains(correo))
{
    emails.Add(correo);
    validMail = true;
}
```

Es fácil de leer y su ejecución es más eficiente que utilizar linq.